# 'It was the only mine still in operation'. Where do I insert 'of six' in that sentence?

Tags: word-order

> It was the only **of six** mines still in operation

? No, 'the only' cannot be used as a pronoun.

> It was the only mine **of six** still in operation

, maybe? But then it's not clear whether 'still in operation' refers to 'the only mine' or 'six'. Also, note that I would like to avoid saying 'mine(s)' twice. Can it be done without rephrasing?

Comment: What does "mine" mean here?  A hole in the ground?  A type of bomb? or the pronoun meaning "my one".

Comment: And are you trying to say that there used to be six mines in operation, but now there is only one?

Comment: @JamesK A place where ore is extracted

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both do not clearly and naturally convey what is intended. The second is closest, but only *just* works if punctuated as:

> It was the only mine, of the six, still in operation.

A much better way to phrase it would be:

> Of the six mines, it was the only one still in operation.

Comment: Why did you put 'the' before the numeral?

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t notice I’d done this. You are right that I told you it just needed punctuation, but then I added “the” as well as punctuation. 

It would be even less natural without “the” since it is essentially saying: “THE only mine of THE six mines”